# Tool or script to read lines (call data) from a file and create output files for each call

Tags: loops, awk, sed, grep, readline

I'm a PBX admin and not a coder, but am trying to figure out how to use a `for` loop and some tool (`grep`/`awk`/`sed`/?) to read lines in a call record log file (*cdrLog-D0202017.txt*) and produce a text file for each call. 
All call data is sequential and Calls begin with a line "*CDR BEGIN*" followed by some lines with call events then ends that call with a line "*CDR END*". 
I'm in Windows CMD scripting but will move the logs to wherever I can create a solution.

I've tried using `grep` and `find` to find the "*CDR BEGIN*" and thought I could calculate the number of line to the next one in a loop and then output all lines from the first "*CDR Begin*" to the next one. So far I'm just confusing myself. I realize that *REGEX* or `awk` may be a better way to go. I'm looking for a pointer in the right direction if anyone has advice. I think I've been trying hammers and saws when there may be a better tool.

There are thousands of these call records in each day's log file. I'd like to output each record into its own file named by some data in the call like *time* (example *021817-235835.call*) - Basically I'm trying to make call data objects out of serial logged data.

Example call data record from the log file (these are flat ACSII files Windows created):

```
===== CDR BEGIN : 02/18/17 23:58:35.994 =====

    00:00:00.000 [  TS] SYSTEM ID = TheBigSystem
    00:00:00.000 [ CIM] Incoming Call (ID: 911001-10233-20170320035835) Offered on Trunk 9110001<BR>
    00:00:02.269 [ CIM] ANI: (40)"8885551212" [VALID] PseudoANI: "" [NONE]
    00:00:02.269 [  TS] Initial ALI Request for ANI : 8005551212
    00:00:02.276 [ CIM] Call Presented
    ... several lines of details ...
    00:01:39.019 [ CIM] Call Disconnected
    00:01:39.025 [ CIM] Call Terminated
    00:01:39.025 [  TS] Call Completed
    =====   Initial ALI   ====
    (888) 555-1212   23:58    02/18
        3452        N SomeLong HWY -
    N                               
    Wonderland   MN 564 WRLS
    Telephone provider name              
                         P# 512-1234
    ALT# 888-555-1212    LEC:SomeLEC
    WIRELESS CALL
    QUERY CALLER FOR LOCATION
    QUERY CALLER FOR PHONE # 
    -090.263862 +16.123140

===== CDR END =====
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
/^===== CDR BEGIN/ { f=$0; gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",f) }   # output filename is all digits from BEGIN
f{ b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0 }                         # when flag up all records to buffer
/^===== CDR END/ { print b > f; close(f); b=f="" } # output and reset variables
' file
$ ls 
021817235835994
file
```

Variable `f` acts as a flag for gathering the records for output and the filename holder. Not sure if flag is really needed since you only posted 1 CDR and I don't know if there is anything between the CDRs that needs to be weeded out. Filename is created by removing all non-digits from the `CDR BEGIN` record. `b` is the buffer for records to be outputed.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with this a bit more to get your file name as desired, but should get you going:

```
awk '/CDR BEGIN/{out=gensub(/[[:punct:]]/,"","g",$5 $6)".call"}{print > out}' your_file
```

This will currently produce files like:

```
021817235835994.call
```

The code simply finds each time it hits the "CDR BEGIN" string and then strips all the punctuation from the fifth and sixth items, which are the date and time.  Then it is a simple case of outputting to your new file name